# Symfony2 createQueryBuilder filter records on weekdays

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with a query. I need to select records on a specific day in a week, for example all records on Monday.
I don't know how to tell the querybuilder to look only for specific weekdays.

Here is my code:

```
public function getBookingSerial($dStart) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->andWhere($this->createQueryBuilder('b')->expr()->like('b.start', ':start'))
        ->setParameter('start', '____-__-__ '.$dStart->format('H:i').':__')
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `start` is stored in a column of the Doctrine type `datetime`, you will not be able to do the query you want in DQL (or trough the `QueryBuilder`) because the day of the week must be computed: it is not present directly in the date and a `LIKE` isn't sufficient.

All DBMS provide date and time manipulation functions. For instance [MySQL has a `DAYOFWEEK()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) doing what you want but Doctrine doesn't support them natively.

Some libraries including [Luxifer Doctrine Functions](https://github.com/luxifer/doctrine-functions) provide DQL extensions to support date and time function. With this library installed you can just do the following:

```
public function getBookingSerial($dStart) {
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->andWhere('DAYOFWEEK(u.b) = 2')
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

An alternative is to use [native queries](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html). It doesn't require any external library but it will work only on your specific DBMS:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('Booking', 'b');
$rsm->addFieldResult('b', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('b', 'start', 'start');
// finish your mapping here

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('SELECT id, start FROM Booking WHERE DAYOFWEEK(start) = 2', $rsm);
// Monday is index 2

$users = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks! I go with Luxifer